# Even pages on two-sided document on right - setcounter problem?

Tags: counters, double-sided, setcounter

I have a two-sided document, where the table of contents (TOC) is in Roman numbering.
Afterwards I use Arabic numbering for the main part, and afterwards Roman numbering for the bibliography (BIB) again.
I have the following problem:

- The TOC ends with III, I save the current page in a counter (it ends with III)
- After the main part, I resume the counter
- So I want to start the BIB with IV on the right side (new page)
- What I get is a V, starting on the right side

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,
    openright
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{savepage}

\begin{document}
% Intro in Roman
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Intro}
\lipsum[1-12]

% Main part in arabic
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}} % save roman counter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Main Part}
\lipsum[1-12]

% Additional stuff in Roman
% Should start from IV on right page
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage} % load old roman counter
\chapter*{Appendix}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

I guess the problem is because of "new chapters" (cleardoublepage) start on the right side and LaTeX wants to assign an uneven number to right sided pages?
But I'm not quite sure - can anybody help me here?

Greetings

Matse

Comment: all the settings of margins and page styles assume odd page number on the right, there is no test for left or right page other than odd or even page number so having page 4 on the right would be very odd and not that easy to do

Comment: OK I see - so you mean I shouldn't change it (even if I intuitionally think that starting with IV would be nicer)? I mean the jump from III to V just looks unnatural to me.

Comment: restarting the Roman page numbering for the bib is simply nonsense. How should a reader know if page IV is at the begin or at the end of the book? Either continue with arabic numbering for the bib or use there roman numbering. Beside this: use scrbook and \frontmatter and \mainmatter instead of resetting all counters manually.

Comment: How do you mean this? In the TOC it's clear where IV starts. Otherwise it's not my own idea - the university wants me to use Roman numbering for the Bibliography... and in the "template" it starts at IV.

Comment: so if you text says something like "see page VI" you expect the reader to go to the table of contents to figure out if this is at the begin or the end of the book by checking the page number of the bibliography? And yes I know that this nonsense is propagated in some templates, the question pops up quite regularly in german tex groups and I always refused to help to implement it.

Comment: Luckily I don't refer to pages on my bibliography, but just to certain entries (by number, using IEEE style) - so at least this is in my case no problem... even of course if I get what you mean.

Comment: apart from the general weirdness and undesirability of having even pages on the right, in this case you _want_  5 as (as shown by your save/restore code) that is the next natural page number that would have been printed had you not switched to arabic for the main document. Page 4 is the blank page thrown by `\cleardoublepage` it is set with `\pagestyle{empty}`  so the page number isn't printed but it is still page iv. You could use a version of `\cleardoublepage`  that printed page numbers on blank pages.

Comment: Why don't you use `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{Roman}` to distinguish between initial and final pages?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I spoke with my supervisor today and told him the concerns with the roman numbering at the end and he understands the problem and fully agrees to continue using arabic numbering... So problem solved :)